# Connecting to PiHole via OpenVPN on Asus Router

Tags: dns

I've configured and can successfully connect via OpenVPN on my Asus router.

When I'm away from home, I'd like to be able to continue using pihole for dns - heres what i've tried

```
# pihole runs on 192.168.1.150
# added this to openvpn server.conf
push "dhcp-option DNS 192.168.1.150"
```

Here is also a sample from my `client.ovpn`, which i added when the server conf DNS config failed

```
...etc
auth SHA1
ns-cert-type server
dhcp-option DNS 192.168.1.150
...etc
```

Here is log output from my IOS openvpn client

[image]

In my case it looks like I've successfully added my pihole DNS to the VPN connection, but the client fails to block ad requests.

I'm testing this using https://blockads.fivefilters.org/?pihole

If I disconnect VPN and switch back to wifi, the pihole test works as expected for DNS 192.168.1.150, so i've triple checked its the correct IP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working!!! Turns out I had not correctly setup the DNS in my WAN settings (but I had for LAN) - I guess the WAN settings needed to be updated because my PI is on the wireless network?

[image]

[image]

[image]